# How to add datefield in datagrid

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3, flash-builder

I have a datagrid with editable property and inside a column to display date information.
Dates are storing in a dataprovider as string format. (those dates come from database with httpservice).
But I'd like to add an itemEditor on my datagrid column.
To do that, I try

```
 <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="echElemDate"  headerText="MyHeaderDate" 
     headerStyleName="dgHeader" fontWeight="normal" 
      itemEditor="mx.controls.DateField" editorDataField="text"/>
```

But when I click on this cell, an error appear :

```
Type Coercion failed: cannot convert "29/07/2015" to Date
```

So can you help me to solve this mistake.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

use editorDataField="selectedDate". because when edit end, it will convert DateField[editorDataField] to data[dataField]

Answer (score 0):

try changing headerText = DateString and make sure you insert mx:datagrid editable="true"

Comment: Thanks for you answer but it didn't solve my problem. Indeed, my datagrid is editable and headerText is not the problem

Answer (score 0):

If inside your dataprovider you have AS objects with a controlable AS class, the easiest way is to add a getter and a setter in your class with a conversion String<>Date using [DateField](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/DateField.html#stringToDate%28%29), like this :

```
public function get echElemDateAsDate():Date {
    return DateField.stringToDate(this.echElemDate, "DD/MM/YYYY");
}

public function set echElemDateAsDate(value:Date) {
     this.echElemDate = DateField.dateToString(value, "DD/MM/YYYY");
}
```

If you don't have the control over the class, then I think you have to do a custom item editor

Comment: Inside my dataprovider, I have no AS object. So could I use your answer inside itemrenderer with override set and get data method?

Comment: Yes for the set data. Not sure for the get, I don't remember how the data from an item editor are put back in the dataprovider.

Answer (score 0):

@huang.xinghui gave you useful advice, did you try this code? I reproduced your situation and this helped.

```
<mx:DataGridColumn dataField="echElemDate"  headerText="MyHeaderDate" 
                               headerStyleName="dgHeader" fontWeight="normal" 
                               itemEditor="mx.controls.DateField" editorDataField="selectedDate"/>
```